# Working with Spring WebServiceMessage

Tags: xml, spring, soap, webservicetemplate

I have code that uses Spring's `WebServiceTemplate` to invoke a SOAP service.

Currently it uses:

```
public Object marshalSendAndReceive(String uri, final Object requestPayload)
```

But I would like to manipulate the content both inbound and outbound. The most suitable public method appears to be:

```
public <T> T sendAndReceive(String uriString,
    WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback,
    WebServiceMessageExtractor<T> responseExtractor)
```

... for which I would provide a custom callback and extractor.

The interfaces for those both specify methods that work with a `WebServiceMessage`.

```
public interface WebServiceMessage {

    Source getPayloadSource();
    Result getPayloadResult();
    void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException;

}
```

`Source` and `Result` are both interfaces from the `javax.xml.transform`, and they don't seem to expose message content. Both just have a setter and getter for `String systemId`, and nothing else.

I can see that there are various implementations of `Source`, all providing different access to the payload. I could do something like this in my callback:

```
   StreamSource source = (StreamSource) message.getPayloadSource();
```

But casting is dirty, and anyway, how do I know which implementations I should support?

How can I get at this content (ideally the raw XML)?